# Selenium find_element_by_id returns None

Tags: selenium-ide, python-2.6

I am using selenium and i have properly installed the selenium module on redhat linux 6.
Below is my script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import unittest, time, re
import zlib


class Sele1(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "https://bugzilla.example.com/"
        self.verificationErrors = []

    def test_sele1(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url + "/")
        driver.find_element_by_id("Bugzilla_login").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("Bugzilla_login").send_keys("username")
        driver.find_element_by_id("Bugzilla_password").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("Bugzilla_password").send_keys("password")
        driver.find_element_by_id("log_in").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("quicksearch").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("quicksearch").send_keys("new bugs is bugzilla tool")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Find Bugs']").click()

    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException, e: return False
        return True

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

When i am running this script it is showing errors:

### ERROR: test_sele1 (**main**.Sele1)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sele1.py", line 19, in test_sele1
    driver.find_element_by_id("Bugzilla_login").clear()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clear'

---

Ran 1 test in 2.018s

FAILED (errors=1)

Plateform: Redhat
Python Version: 2.6

Note: while running the same script in windows7, it is running fine but not running in linux with python2.6

Please help me for this...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please start by unwrapping the fluff to get to the initial cause. Nobody cares that `None.clear()` was invoked.

Comment: but the same script is running in windows why?

Comment: If `clear` is removed it won't change the source of the issue, which is what I put in the updated title. It'll just break on the `send_keys` line. Hurrah. This is why it's important to remove the fluff.

Comment: if i remove the ".clear()" in this line "driver.find_element_by_id("Bugzilla_login").clear()" then it is showing the same error for "send_keys" also

Comment: Find out what `find_element_by_id` returns null, as per the title.

Comment: how can i see this thing because the output will come in the html form..so i cant check for this. if any other way is there then i dont aware with that because i my new to this selenium....

Comment: For now just forget about the clear attribute. Take send_key attribute and this is also not working. And in this we passed the value username..the same script is working in windows

Comment: Please read what I said. `find_element_by_id(..)` returns `None`. Of course it won't work until *that* is fixed. That is why the "fluff" is removed, so we can see the real issue (it has *nothing* to do with `clear` or `send_key`), why is `find_element_by_id(..)` returning None? I have no idea ..

Answer (score 0):

Simple: Selenium can't find an element called "Bugzilla_login".

There could be hundreds of reasons this may be happening.  I'd start with checking whether you're loading the correct page.